# Pandas "mask" slows down PowerBI Query?

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi-desktop

I'm using Python/pandas as a datasource to load and manipulate a dataframe from an Excel sheet. 
I'm creating a column 'RollProd' based off of values in column 'Product'.

The lines in question that are slowing down my query so much were previously:

```
colsearch = ['FC4', 'NC4', 'IC4', 'RGB']
finaldf['RollProd'] = np.where(finaldf['Product'].str.contains(r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(colsearch)), case=False, na=False), 'C4', 'C3')
```

which checks to see if the entries in column 'Product' contain 'C3' or 'C4', and then populates 'RollProd' accordingly.

This was fast, but after more products were added (I needed more than a true/false result) I decided to use masks:

```
mask_0 =((finaldf['Product'].str.contains('C4', case=False, na=False)) | (finaldf['Product'].str.contains('RGB', case=False, na=False)))
mask_1 = (finaldf['Product'].str.contains('CON', case=False, na=False))
mask_2 = (finaldf['Product'].str.contains('C3', case=False, na=False))
mask_3 = (finaldf['Product'].str.contains('MIX', case=False, na=False))
finaldf.loc[mask_0, 'RollProd'] = 'C4'
finaldf.loc[mask_1, 'RollProd'] = 'C5+'
finaldf.loc[mask_2, 'RollProd'] = 'C3'
finaldf.loc[mask_3, 'RollProd'] = 'MIX'
```

This works just as quickly when I run the script on its own, but when I change the PowerBI query it takes hours to load. 
Is there a better method than mask, or is there something inefficient with my code?

Comment: You might look at using list comprehension verus .str accessor methods.  Pandas string accessor method are pretty slow.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @ScottBoston , I'll try that next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) which will work faster than using `.loc` four times.
It takes a list of conditions and the matching choices.

```
conditions = [mask_0, mask_1, mask_2, mask_3]
choices = ['C4', 'C5+', 'C3', 'MIX']

finaldf['RollProd'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='unknown')
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Erfan, this worked liked a charm. Is there a particular reason you know of why the time was so drastically increased from just the script vs running in PowerBI?

Comment: Im not sure in this particular case. But whenever I face issues with speed. I always try to look for a `numpy` solution, since these vectorized solutions are optimized down to cython. @poorpractice

Comment: thank you again, one more question. The refresh came through fine on the desktop using that method, but it's still too slow on the server. Is there anything else you might suggest to speed it up a bit more?